# how to skip more than one line using continue

Tags: java, netbeans, bufferedreader

I am using a buffered reader to read in a file and i want to skip over 4 lines rather than just one using the continue method shown below, any suggestions?

```
if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: post the whole code

Comment: You could set a variable to 4, and then have `if (skip > 0) { --skip; continue; }` elsewhere in your loop

Comment: What are we continuing here? Give us teh codez

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
int skipNumberOfLines = 0;
while(read){
   if(skipNumberOfLines > 0){
      skipNumberOfLines--;
      continue;
   }

   if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) {
      skipNumberOfLines = 3;
      continue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "eat" other lines before continue e.g.:

```
[...]

if (trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) {
    skipLines(4);
    continue;
}

[...]

    private void skipLines(int num, BufferedReader in){
       for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
       in.readLine();
       }
    }
```